# Find 1st # in Sequence

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of numbers and I want to return a list of #'s of the first # in a sequence.

So this list {1,2,5,7,8,9}

i want to return {1,5,7}

1 since 1,2 is a sequence and 1 is the first # in it

5 since it isnt in a sequence

7 since 7,8,9 is a sequence and 7 is the first # in it.

I'm thinking if i loop thru them and check if there is a number in the list that comes before the current # in the loop i can determine this, but im wondering if i can do this with linq?

Comment: I haven't thought about it much, but you can probably use the LINQ `Aggregate()` method to accomplish your goal. But first you should try _something_. Explain what you've tried, what happened, and how that was different from what you wanted. Show your work. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you seem to be asking for:

```
int[] data = { 1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9 };
var result = data.Aggregate(new List<List<int>>(), (list, item) =>
{
    List<int> previousList = list.Count > 0 ? list[list.Count - 1] : null;

    if (previousList != null && item == previousList[previousList.Count - 1] + 1)
    {
        previousList.Add(item);
    }
    else
    {
        list.Add(new List<int> { item });
    }

    return list;
});

foreach (List<int> list in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sequence: " + string.Join(", ", list));
}
```

Comment: yes that will work if i change the last foreach to
    foreach (List<int> list in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(list.Min());
    }

Answer (score 0):

For my own personal learning, I had a go at it and came up with a successful result, however the other answers look much nicer and are probably more efficient. At any rate, here is what I did:

```
List<int> myInts = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9 }.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
List<List<int>> Sequences = new List<List<int>>();
foreach(var i in myInts)
{
    var seq = Sequences.Where(x => x.Contains(i - 1));
    if (seq.Count() > 0)
        seq.First().Add(i);
    else
        Sequences.Add(new List<int> { i });
}
var firstItems = Sequences.Select(x => x.First()).ToList();

//Result: 1, 5, 7
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
var query =
    list
        .Skip(1)
        .Aggregate(new
        {
            results = list.Take(1).ToList(),
            last = list.First()
        }, (a, x) =>
        {
            if (x > a.last + 1)
            {
                a.results.Add(x);
            }
            return new { a.results, last = x };
        }).results;
```